# Return multiple lists with foreach

Tags: r

I am doing some kmeans clustering analysis. Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(foreach)

my_diamonds <- diamonds %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% scale %>% as.data.frame
try_centers <- seq(from = 3, to = 12, by = 1)

wss_list <- foreach(k = try_centers) %do% { # forget parallel processing with this size of data not enough ram
  print(k) # progress bar
  hw = kmeans(my_diamonds, centers = k, iter.max = 20, nstart = 3, algorithm = 'Hartigan-Wong') 
}

wss <- lapply(wss_list, function(i) i$tot.withinss) %>% unlist()
plot(try_centers, wss)
```

This returns a within sum of squares variance plot:
[image]

But I would like to compare with two other algorithms in kmeans. Tried:

```
wss_list <- foreach(k = try_centers) %do% { # forget parallel processing with this size of data not enough ram
  print(k) # progress bar
  hw = kmeans(my_diamonds, centers = k, iter.max = 20, nstart = 3, algorithm = 'Hartigan-Wong') 
  lloyd = kmeans(my_diamonds, centers = k, iter.max = 20, nstart = 3, algorithm = 'Lloyd')
  mac = kmeans(my_diamonds, centers = k, iter.max = 20, nstart = 3, algorithm = 'MacQueen')
}

wss <- lapply(wss_list, function(i) i$tot.withinss) %>% unlist()
plot(try_centers, wss)
```

This does return a plot, but which one am I looking at?! MaQueen? Lloyd?

How can I structure this to run kmeans with the three algorithms on each iteration and then plot on one chart each of the 3?

Comment: You need to return a `list(hw, lloyd, mac)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we don't specify the `return`, it will return only the last object created.  We can have a `list` of objects in `return`

```
wss_list <- foreach(k = try_centers) %do% { # forget parallel processing with this size of data not enough ram
  print(k) # progress bar
  hw = kmeans(my_diamonds, centers = k, iter.max = 20, nstart = 3, algorithm = 'Hartigan-Wong') 
  lloyd = kmeans(my_diamonds, centers = k, iter.max = 20, nstart = 3, algorithm = 'Lloyd')
  mac = kmeans(my_diamonds, centers = k, iter.max = 20, nstart = 3, algorithm = 'MacQueen')
  
  return(dplyr::lst(hw, lloyd, mac))
}
```

Then, we can extract each components

```
library(purrr)
hw <- map(wss_list, ~ .x$hw)
lloyd <- map(wss_list, ~ .x$lloyd)
mac <- map(wss_list, ~ .x$mac)
```

---

Or `transpose` the `list` to create a `list`  of three

```
wss_list1 <- wss_list %>%
              transpose 
names(wss_list1)
#[1] "hw"    "lloyd" "mac"
```

Now, we `plot` as

```
wss <- lapply(wss_list1$hw, function(i) i$tot.withinss) %>% 
       unlist()
plot(try_centers, wss)
```

[image]

and the same way, we do it with other components

```
wss2 <- lapply(wss_list1$lloyd, function(i) i$tot.withinss) %>% 
      unlist()
plot(try_centers, wss2)
```